# Using arrays by reference

Tags: php, arrays, reference

Why is the following code "crashing" in PHP?

```
$normal_array       = array();
$array_of_arrayrefs = array( &$normal_array );

end( $array_of_arrayrefs )["one"] = 1; // choking on this one
```

The expected result is that the final code line appends `$normal_array` with key `one` having value `1` but there is no output what so ever, not even prints preceeding this code. In the real context of this scenario I use end() function to always append to the last array reference.

Comment: When you saying "crashing" do you mean "reporting a syntax error" or "throwing a runtime error" of some description?

Comment: No output what so ever, not even prints preceeding this code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use array-references inside arrays in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191883/how-can-i-use-array-references-inside-arrays-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't crash, it just contains a syntax error:

```
end( $array_of_arrayrefs )["one"] = 1;
```

Unfortunately, you cannot treat function return values as arrays in PHP. You have to assign the value explicitly. Unfortunately, this doesn't work here because `end` makes a copy of the returned value.